# Recommendation for batch processing on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm new to using AWS, so any pointers would be appreciated.
I have a need to process large files using our in-house software.

It takes about 2GB of input and generates 5GB of output, running for 2 hours on a c3.8xlarge.

For now I do it manually, start an instance (either on-demand or spot-request), but now I want to reliably automate and scale this processing - what are good frameworks or platform or amazon services to do that?
Especially regarding the possibility that a spot-instance will be terminated half-way through (and I'll need to detect that and restart the job).

I heard about Python Celery, but does it work well with amazon and spot-instances?
Or are there other recommended mechanisms?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat opinion-based, but you can mix and match some of the AWS pieces to make this easier:

- put the input data on S3
- push an entry into a SQS queue indicating a job needs to be processed with a long visibility timeout
- set up an [autoscaling policy based on SQS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/as-using-sqs-queue.html) with your machine description in CloudFormation.
- use [UserData/cloudinit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/deploying.applications.html) to set up the machine and start your application
- write code to receive the queue entry, start processing, finish processing, then delete the SQS message.
- code should check for another queued entry. If none, code should terminate machine.